# Using Flask-Login and Flask-Babel together

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, flask-babel

I am constructing a multi-language app using Flask as well as using Flask-Login for authentication.

My typical views look like this:

```
@auth.route('/en/login/', endpoint="login_en", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@auth.route('/es/login/', endpoint="login_es", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    ...
```

Whilst I deal with language preferences like so:

```
@babel.localeselector
def get_locale():
    """Get user language."""
    if 'static' not in request.path:
        languages = app.config.get('LANGUAGES').keys()
        lang = request.path.rstrip('/').split('/')[-1]
        if lang in languages:
            return lang
        elif request.accept_languages:
            return request.accept_languages.best_match(languages)
        else:
            return 'en'


@app.before_request
def before_request():
    """Store data in session before each request."""
    ...
    g.language = get_locale()
```

Now Flask-Login requires a default login route, which is typically set like so:

```
login_manager.login_view = "auth.login"
```

I can set this to a default language route (e.g. `auth.login_en`), but ideally I would like to process the language preference beforehand so the user gets the best-fit login view. I thought about having a dummy view:

```
@auth.route('/_login/', methods=['GET'])
def _login():
    return redirect(url_for('auth.login_' + g.language), code=302)
```

.. which determines the language preference and then redirects to the correct language view, but that seems a little clunky.

Comment: [This](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#localization) might help (2 years later, I know...).

Comment: I'm working with an app which is translated with flask-babel and all works fine apart from the login page. I suspect it's somehow related to flask-login and your question is the only one I found that deals with using these modules together successfully, can you tell me how you made them work? [Here's my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845472/flask-babel-not-working-on-the-login-page).