# Flask-Babel not working on the login page

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash, flask-babel

I have a **[Flask/Dash](https://dash.plot.ly/introduction)** app that uses the **[Flask-Babel](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Babel/)** module. The translation works like a charm after logging in and browsing through pages. However, I cannot make it work for the login page which will always be displayed in English. The `messages.po` and `messages.mo` both contain the translation strings I prepared for the login page, so the compilation part seems to work fine.

Here's a snippet from my `app.py` (with a hard-coded choice of Spanish):

```py
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_babel import Babel
# some more imports...

# (...)

def main():

    update_dataframes()

    app = dash.Dash(
        "MyApp",
        url_base_pathname='/summary',
        static_folder="static",
        sharing=True,
        csrf_protect=False
    )

    # Hook Flask-Babel to the app
    babel = Babel(app.server)

    @babel.localeselector
    def get_locale():
        # return request.accept_languages.best_match(context.config['LANGUAGES'].keys())
        return 'es'

    # App layout
    app.layout = build_app_layout(context)

    # Setup callbacks
    setup_callbacks(app)
    setup_login(app, app.server, context.config)

    # Start Dash/Flask app
    app.server.run(
        port=context.config['DEPLOY']['SERVER_PORT'],
        debug=context.config['DEPLOY']['SERVER_DEBUG'],
        threaded=context.config['DEPLOY']['SERVER_THREADED']
    )

    # Interval tread to update all dataframes
    ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1).submit(update_dataframes_thread)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Below, a part of the `setup_login(...)` method called above. I'd like to notice that `app.server` is passed to it from the code above, *after* Flask-Babel has been hooked to the app (don't really know if that matters much):

```
from dash_flask_login import FlaskLoginAuth
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, logout_user
# (...)

login_app = Dash(
    name='login-app',
    url_base_pathname='/login',
    server=app.server
)
```

**What I tried:** hooking the Flask-Babel again for the `login_app` Dash() instance, but that didn't work (anyways it's still the same `app.server`).

I've come across [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42375487/flask-flask-security-babel-not-working) with a similar problem, but it seems to be specific to Flask-Security module (not my case).

What am I missing to make the login page translated?

Comment: [This](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#localization) might do the trick for you.

Comment: Thanks, although that helps translating the flash messages, the login page itself still stays in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I haven't found a direct reason why a combination of **Dash** and **Flask-Login** don't work with **Flask-Babel** on the login page, I solved the problem with a workaround - I'm dynamically updating generated HTML component through [Dash's callback decorator](https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started-part-2) just after loading the page. The function simply substitutes the original English `some_string` with `gettext(some_string)` tag which is detected properly in the callbacks. This way the page loads in English and immediately gets translated, as the callbacks come to action. Minimal example:

```py
app.layout = html.Div(
        [
            html.H1('Hello World!', id='h1'),
            html.Div(html.A('login', href='/login')
        ]
    )


# Display the message translated to another language
@app.callback(
    Output('h1', 'children'),
    [Input('url', 'search')]
)
def translate_message(children):
    return gettext('Hello World!')
```